# Generating date aggregation and query at same request with Postgres similar to Elasticsearch

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch

What would be the best way to query a timeseries data set, with both generating a filter, and using a date histogram over that time, similar to log services? For instance, in Elasticsearch, you can query the following in the one request and runs pretty fast:

```
GET data-3/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "resource_type.keyword": {
              "value": "device"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "recordedAt": {
              "gte": "now-6M",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "0": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "recordedAt",
        "interval": "month"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which would both filter using expressions, return the top 10 hits, and also aggregate the date histogram in the same response. I've tried some CTE expressions but not sure they would be the best way. I've tried the following hack to build a JSON object on the fly (sorry) but stuck with `Subquery must return only one column`:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT *
           FROM data d
           WHERE d.data >= '2022-04-07T00:00:00'::timestamp
             AND d.recorded_at <= '2022-10-07T00:00:00'::timestamp
             AND d.resource_type = 'device')
SELECT jsonb_build_object('aggregation', (SELECT COUNT(*), date(x.recorded_at) FROM x GROUP BY 2))
```

What I want to end up is similar to:

```
   WITH x AS (SELECT *
               FROM data d
               WHERE d.recorded_at >= '2022-04-07T00:00:00'::timestamp
                 AND d.recorded_at <= '2022-10-07T00:00:00'::timestamp
                 AND d.resource_type = 'device')
    SELECT jsonb_build_object(
        'aggregation', (SELECT COUNT(*), date(x.recorded_at) FROM x GROUP BY 2)
        'results', (SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY x.recorded_at LIMIT 10)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `json_build_object` correctly, each of its arguments must be a single value, e.g.

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT
        1 AS x,
        2 AS y,
        3 AS z
)
SELECT
    jsonb_build_object(
        'a', (SELECT x FROM t), 
        'b', (SELECT y FROM t), 
        'c', (SELECT z FROM t));
```

As for the query, you can do without a CTE, like this

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*), date(x.recorded_at) 
           FROM data_change_records d
           WHERE d.recorded_at >= '2022-04-07T00:00:00'::timestamp
             AND d.recorded_at <= '2022-10-07T00:00:00'::timestamp
             AND d.resource_type = 'device')
GROUP BY 2
```

If you want to wrap this in json, that can be done in a similar way to the following example:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(cnt, dt)) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, date(x.recorded_at) AS dt
               FROM data_change_records d
               WHERE d.recorded_at >= '2022-04-07T00:00:00'::timestamp
                 AND d.recorded_at <= '2022-10-07T00:00:00'::timestamp
                 AND d.resource_type = 'device')
    GROUP BY 2
) sub;
```

As an aside, be careful with date predicates which are inclusive inequalities on both sides.

Comment: CTE is for executing two queries using the same data. One returns top N results ordered by date field, other is the date histogram.

Comment: You should be able to apply the above structure to your edited query.